# Query % of x item based on x+y total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a SQL command which returns me the following table

[image]

What I need now, is to retrieve how much % corretiva is from total, and how much % preventiva is from total for each month, so there must be another 2 columns like `preventivas%` and `corretivas%` as example, I know `MES.1 (month 1)`, will return `preventiva =100%`, and `corretiva = 0%`,

This is my query

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(workOrderDate) AS MES, 
    (SUM(CASE WHEN WorkType = '02' AND workOrderDescription = 'preventiva' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)) AS preventiva,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN workOrderDescription = 'CORRETIVA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS corretivas,
    SUM(CASE WHEN WorkType = '02' AND workOrderDescription = 'preventiva' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN workOrderDescription = 'CORRETIVA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM 
    WorkOrder 
WHERE 
    YEAR(workOrderDate) = 2018 
    AND lastUpdateData IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(workOrderDate);
```

I can't seem to figure out how to achieve the wanted result, would anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Just use the basic formula for % (ex: `preventive`/`total`*100)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ? Is this MySQL, or something else ?

Comment: I'm using sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take your existing query, put it into a CTE, and then calculate your percentages in the main SELECT, like this:

```
;WITH subresults AS
(
    SELECT
        MES = MONTH(workOrderDate)
        ,preventiva = ( SUM(CASE WHEN WorkType = '02'
                                     AND workOrderDescription = 'preventiva'
                                     THEN 1.0
                                ELSE 0 END
                        )
                      )
        ,corretivas = ( SUM(CASE WHEN workOrderDescription = 'CORRETIVA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
        ,total = SUM(CASE WHEN WorkType = '02'
                              AND workOrderDescription = 'preventiva'
                              THEN 1.0
                         ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN workOrderDescription = 'CORRETIVA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                 )
    FROM WorkOrder
    WHERE
        YEAR(workOrderDate) = 2018
        AND lastUpdateData IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY MONTH(workOrderDate)
)
SELECT 
    s.MES
    ,s.preventiva
    ,s.corretivas
    ,s.total 
    ,preventivasPct = CASE WHEN s.total <> 0 THEN (s.preventiva / s.total) * 100.0 ELSE NULL END
    ,corretivasPct = CASE WHEN s.total <> 0 THEN (s.corretivas / s.total) * 100.0 ELSE NULL END
FROM subresults s
```

EDIT: I added `CASE` statements to `preventivasPct` and `corretivasPct`. When the total is 0, the CASE will return `NULL`. Feel free to change `NULL` to some other value if you want. I've found that usually `0` or `NULL` is the correct answer when encountered with divide-by-zero when calculating percentages.

Comment: In my case, some values will be 0, so i'ts returning me an error `divide by 0 error encountered` how can I handle that?

Comment: With a `CASE` statement. Just a sec and I will update my answer.

Comment: @MatheusBatista You can use `NULLIF(column, 0)` also, it gives to you NULL value.